# Names in geom_bar with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need some help with this graph, here's my code

```
ggplot(aes(x=situa_ence,fill=cs_sexo), data=dados) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))
```

I need to put names in each bar

[image]

(1 =Sick, 2 = Not sick )

Comment: Wouldn't it be more convenient to just rename the x-axis instead? Just renaming `sutia_ence` should do

Comment: I concur with @erocar also because writing the names in the bar might cause confusion, as viewers might not understand whether you mean the whole bar, or just the filled part where you write your names. Otherwise, you could use something like `annotate("text", x = 1, y = 0.5, label = "sick") + annotate("text", x = 2, y = 0.1, label = "not sick")` in your ggplot call.

Answer (score 0):

Use ifelse()

```
dados$situa_ence <- ifelse(dados$situa_ence == 1, yes = "Sick", no = "Not sick")
```